# How can I extract data from Packed Record with external DLL using Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm making some delphi program using external DLL.
The DLL supports when a request occurs sending window message to client.

I defined packed record like below:

```
type

  // Message Packet that send from DLL
  TRECV_PACKET = Packed Record
    nID: Integer;
    lpData: Pointer;
  end;
  LPRECV_PACKET = ^TRECV_PACKET;

  // Request record
  ReqBlock = Packed Record
    id: array [0..7] of Char
  end;
  LPReqBlock = ^ReqBlock;

  // Response record
  ResBlock = Packed Record
    title: array[0..255] of Char; _dt: Char;
    description: array[0..1204] of Char; _time: Char;
  end;
  LPResBlock = ^ResBlock;
```

If I send a request, the DLL send a window message to my client.
I found out some explanation in document.
The DLL sends `RECV_PACKET`'s `memory address` in `Message.LParam`.
As a result, I want to get datas of `ResBlock` using `Message.LParam`.
But the code that I wrote is just send broken datas always.
I want to get pure data from it. How can I do?

Receiving message procedure is below:

```
procedure TForm.OnReceiveData(var Message: TMessage);
var
  recvPacket: LPRECV_PACKET;
  _resBlock: LPResBlock;
begin
  // Actually, I don't know why Message.LParam is parameter of LPRECV_PACKET. How it 
  recvPacket := LPRECV_PACKET(Message.LParam); works? 
  _resBlock := LPResBlock(recvPacket^.lpData);

  ShowMessage(_resBlock^.title); // Broken datas...
end;
```

UPDATED:

The original API definition is below:

```
function ETK_Request(hWnd: HWND; pszTrCode: PAnsiChar; lpData: Pointer; nDataSize: Integer; bNext: Boolean; pszContinueKey: PAnsiChar; nTimeOut: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external API_DLL;
procedure OnReceiveData(var Message: TMessage); message WM_USER + XM_RECEIVE_DATA;
```

Comment: Its been awhile since I've worked with this kind of stuff, but I remember having issues with the datatypes. You may need AnsiChar instead of Char, etc, but I'm not positive.

Comment: We need to see the original API definition. If this is wrong, we cannot *reverse engineer* the correct one.

Comment: post the function signature from the DLL. @TLama you're right - I'm just guessing based off some assumptions about the DLL ... and waiting for David Heffernan to show up and set us straight ;)

Comment: Thanks. Updated original API definition.

Comment: By the way, can you explain why Message.LParam is parameter of LPRECV_PACKET? @trooper

Comment: Now I met error message. Access violation at address 0040A26F in module 'program.exe'. Read of address 00000012.

Comment: There's insufficient information here. First and most obvious: What does "broken data" mean? Tell exactly what you see, and exactly what you expected to see instead. Beware the `Char` means something different from `AnsiChar` if you're using a version of Delphi released after 2009, so mentioning your Delphi version in the question may be prudent. What you've labeled the "original API definition" isn't really that. What you need to include is the source information you used to write your structure definitions. What makes you sure those record declarations are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have the documentation that you are looking at.  But I did find [this online document](http://www.ebestsec.co.kr/apiguide/guide.jsp?cno=300) (which is not in English), as well as [this header file](https://github.com/irus6/xing/blob/master/IXingAPI.h), and various online examples/translations for VB, C#, and C++.  Based on those, your Delphi code should look more like this:

```
type
  // Message Packet that send from DLL
  TRECV_PACKET = packed record
    nRqID: Integer;
    nDataLength: Integer;
    nTotalDataBufferSize: Integer;
    nElapsedTime: Integer;
    nDataMode: Integer;
    szTrCode: array[0..10] of AnsiChar;
    cCont: array[0..0] of AnsiChar;
    szContKey: array[0..18] of AnsiChar;
    szUserData: array[0..30] of AnsiChar;
    szBlockName: array[0..16] of AnsiChar;
    lpData: PByte;
  end;
  LPRECV_PACKET = ^TRECV_PACKET;

  TMSG_PACKET = packed record
    nRqID: Integer;
    nIsSystemError: Integer;
    szMsgCode: array[0..5] of AnsiChar;
    nMsgLength: Integer;
    lpszMessageData: PByte;
  end;
  LPMSG_PACKET = ^TMSG_PACKET;

  TREAL_RECV_PACKET = packed record
    szTrCode: array[0..3] of AnsiChar;
    nKeyLength: Integer;
    szKeyData: array[0..32] of AnsiChar;
    szRegKey: array[0..32] of AnsiChar;
    nDataLength: Integer;
    pszData: PAnsiChar;
  end;
  LPRECV_REAL_PACKET = ^TRECV_REAL_PACKET;

  // the following records are not documented or defined (where did you get them?),
  // but if the above records are any indication, the fields in these records
  // should be using AnsiChar fields...

  // Request record
  ReqBlock = packed record
    id: array [0..7] of AnsiChar;
  end;
  LPReqBlock = ^ReqBlock;

  // Response record
  ResBlock = packed record
    title: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
    _dt: AnsiChar;
    description: array[0..1204] of AnsiChar;
    _time: AnsiChar;
  end;
  LPResBlock = ^ResBlock;

...

const
  XM_DISCONNECT = 1;
  XM_RECEIVE_DATA = 3;
  XM_RECEIVE_REAL_DATA = 4;
  XM_LOGIN = 5;
  XM_LOGOUT = 6;
  XM_TIMEOUT_DATA = 7;

const
  REQUEST_DATA = 1;
  MESSAGE_DATA = 2;
  SYSTEM_ERROR_DATA = 3;
  RELEASE_DATA = 4;

function ETK_Request(hParentWnd: HWND; pszTrCode: PAnsiChar; lpData: Pointer; nDataSize: Integer; bNext: BOOL; pszContinueKey: PAnsiChar; nTimeOut: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external API_DLL;
procedure ETK_ReleaseMessageData(lp: LPARAM); stdcall; external API_DLL;
procedure ETK_ReleaseRequestData(nRequestID: Integer); stdcall; external API_DLL;
```

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure OnReceiveData(var Message: TMessage); message WM_USER + XM_RECEIVE_DATA;
    ...
  end;

procedure TForm1.OnReceiveData(var Message: TMessage);
var
  recvPacket: LPRECV_PACKET;
  _resBlock: LPResBlock;
  msgPacket: LPMSG_PACKET;
begin
  case Message.WParam of
    REQUEST_DATA: begin
      recvPacket := LPRECV_PACKET(Message.LParam);
      // make sure recvPacket^.nDataLength is actually >= SizeOf(ResBlock)
      // before accessing the data...
      _resBlock := LPResBlock(recvPacket^.lpData);
      ShowMessage(_resBlock^.title);
    end;
    MESSAGE_DATA: begin
      msgPacket := LPMSG_PACKET(Message.LParam);
      //...
      ETK_ReleaseMessageData(Message.LParam);
    end;
    SYSTEM_ERROR_DATA: begin
      msgPacket := LPMSG_PACKET(Message.LParam);
      //...
      ETK_ReleaseMessageData(Message.LParam);
    end;
    RELEASE_DATA: begin
      //...
      ETK_ReleaseRequestData(Message.LParam);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. I exactly work with it. I just changed some code on stackoverflow. So you changed `char` to `AnsiChar` right..? I will try like that. Thanks.

Comment: I tried as you said. But I met error message. "Access violation at address 00520267 in module 'program.exe'. Read of address 000278." I don't know why this message shown..

Comment: @gentlejo: I did more than just change `char` to `AnsiChar`. I fleshed out the `TRECV_PACKET` with more fields that exist in front of the `lpData` field (thus affecting its offset in memory), and I made `OnReceiveData` take `Message.WParam` into account when deciding what to cast `Message.LParam` to.  As for your AV errors, they keep occurring near address 0, which implies you are likely accessing nil pointers that you are not checking for.  Unless you can produce the official documentation (in English), there is not much more we can do here.  You need to debug your code to find the errors.

Comment: Now I can get pure data from it by using AnsiChar. But AV error also shown. So I printed each of data in `TRECV_PACKET`. However I just can get data until `szTrCode`. I cannot get datas after `szTrCode`. It causes AV error I think.. And I don't know why API doesn't send data after `szTrCode`....

Comment: @gentlejo Why don't you do some debugging? You cannot expect us to tell you what is wrong with your code. We cannot see your code, nor can we see the specification of the API you are coding against. Consider picking up the phone and ringing the author of this API to ask for help.

Comment: Solved: The documentation was sucks.. It tells wrong length of the packet position.... Thanks all.